# How to use jsonapi pagination with ember-data 1.13

Tags: ember-data, json-api

Is there any possibility at the moment to use pagination with `ember-data 1.13`?

I have a `jsonapi.org` compatible API with a `next` link in the top-level `links` object. How can I tell my store/response array to load this page?

What I wanna do is something like:

```
actions: {
  loadMore() {
    this.get('model').loadNextPage().then((data) => {
      this.set('model', data);
    });
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My working client-side hack around:

I override ajaxOptions on the adapter to make it possible to directly access a URL with `store.find('model', { loadNext: '/loadMoarLink' })`:

```
ajaxOptions(url, type, options) {
    if(options && options.data && options.data.loadNext) {
        url = options.data.loadNext;
        delete options.data.loadNext
    }
    return this._super(url, type, options);
}
```

To access the links I override the normalizeResponse on the adapter to write the links on the meta object:

```
normalizeResponse: function(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType) {
    let links = payload.links;
    let response = this._super(...arguments);
    if(!get(response, 'meta')) {
        set(response, 'meta', Ember.Object.create());
    }
    set(response, 'meta.links', links);
    return response;
}
```

Then I can access the metadata from the `setupController`:

```
controller.set('meta', Ember.copy(this.store.metadataFor('model'), true));
```

And always query the `next` data:

```
this.store.query('model', {
  loadNext: this.get('controller.meta.links.next')
})
```

Comment: Do you have a repository or JSBin for this? I'd love to try your solution, but I'm having a few issues in ember-cli. It's shocking to me how much work-around is required to access information that's fully part of the jsonapi standard.

Comment: That's exactly what we need to do... until we get Ember Data "sugar" to access links. If this helps somewhat, here is a guide I wrote for Ember 2.3, including a Rails 5 backend with Kaminari: http://emberigniter.com/pagination-in-ember-with-json-api-backend/

Answer (score 0):

Pagination is coming soon https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/2905.

For a temp fix, I redid my server logic so that my pagination links were returned in the `meta` key instead of `links` one. That way I could tap into the `extractMeta` method already present in the `JSONAPISerializer`. Not the best solution, but I think it will hold me over until I can implement the official way.

Comment: Well, changing the Server is not an option for me.

Comment: fair enough, I like your solution